# Summing a result set into one row

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a set of data that has say six rows of decimals that I want to sum up they are group by account code I have a stored proc which is a view that brings the data into entity but I am a bit unsure as to my logic.

```
List<NominalSums> _nominalSums = new List<NominalSums>()
foreach (var items in _nominalData)
{
      using (var db = new ConsolidatedSage50Entities())
      {
                    var accRef = items.ACCOUNT_REF;

                    var clientIdParameter1 = new SqlParameter("@AccountRef", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    clientIdParameter1.Value = accRef;

                    var clientIdParameter2 = new SqlParameter("@SortOrder", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    clientIdParameter2.Value = 321;

                    var clientIdParameter3 = new SqlParameter("@CATEGORY", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                    clientIdParameter3.Value = 5;

                    var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<sp_fuel_sumbalances_Result>("sumbalances @AccountRef, @SortOrder, @CATEGORY", new object[] { clientIdParameter1, clientIdParameter2, clientIdParameter3 }).ToList();


                    foreach (var groupData in result)
                    {       
                        _nominalSums.Add(new NominalSums()
                        {
                            ACCOUNT_REF = groupData.ACCOUNT_REF,
                            BALANCE_MTH11 = groupData.BALANCE_MTH1,
                            SortOrder =(int) groupData.SORT_ORDER,
                            Category = (int) groupData.CATEGORY

                        });
                    }
                }

            }
            return _nominalSums;
        }
```

Obv the above code would print a new line for every results as I am just wanting one line combining the results totals of my stored proc can someone point me in the right direction here.

**Edit 2** 
My Main question is cause my stored proc is as below how would I do the group sum on this stored proc instead As I want to only return one row from the main query which has six rows for a certain set of critera.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sumbalances] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @AccountRef varchar(500),
    @SortOrder int,
    @CATEGORY int
    as
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT        NOMINAL_LEDGER.ACCOUNT_REF, NOMINAL_LEDGER.NAME, NOMINAL_LEDGER.ACCOUNT_TYPE, NOMINAL_LEDGER.BALANCE, NOMINAL_LEDGER.QUICK_RATIO, NOMINAL_LEDGER.SOFA_ID, 
                         NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH1, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH2, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH3, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH4, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH5, 
                         NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH6, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH7, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH8, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH9, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH10, 
                         NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH11, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH12, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR2_MTH1, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR2_MTH2, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR2_MTH3,
FROM            CATEGORY left JOIN
                         NOMINAL_LEDGER ON CATEGORY.CompanyID = NOMINAL_LEDGER.CompanyID
                         WHERE ACCOUNT_REF=@AccountRef AND SORT_ORDER=@SortOrder and CATEGORY=@CATEGORY

END
```

Comment: Why can you not just do the sum in the SP ?

Comment: Cause I need to do a loop an I am not to sure how to do that in my sp

Comment: I think it would probably be easier to do it in your SP, can you post your SP code and what you are trying to do (based off the SP code)?  Maybe make a new question and link to it in here

Comment: @Brad I placed in a edit i dont think it stops so flow of questions as I added it and added it onto the stored procedure tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sudo code, I am not sure what fields you wanted to sum up and I think you said by accountID.  So you need to do 2 things to make this work to get the sum by accountID:

1. Add SUM(FieldsYouWantToSumUpByAccountID) as FieldNameYouWantToCallIt to your select
2. In the Group By I added, you would Group by all the fields you want in your select list (that you are not summing up).  SO ID's, Ref, etc.

t

```
SELECT   SUM(FieldYouWantSummed),     NOMINAL_LEDGER.ACCOUNT_REF, NOMINAL_LEDGER.NAME, NOMINAL_LEDGER.ACCOUNT_TYPE, NOMINAL_LEDGER.BALANCE, NOMINAL_LEDGER.QUICK_RATIO, NOMINAL_LEDGER.SOFA_ID, 
                             NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH1, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH2, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH3, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH4, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH5, 
                             NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH6, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH7, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH8, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH9, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH10, 
                             NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH11, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH12, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR2_MTH1, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR2_MTH2, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR2_MTH3,
    FROM            CATEGORY 
    LEFT JOIN NOMINAL_LEDGER ON CATEGORY.CompanyID = NOMINAL_LEDGER.CompanyID
    WHERE ACCOUNT_REF=@AccountRef 
    AND SORT_ORDER=@SortOrder 
    AND CATEGORY=@CATEGORY
    GROUP BY Account_REF (AND ALL other fields that you want duplicated)
```

If you can provide the list of fields you want selected and the fields you want summed I can update the statement above for you if it is not clear.

Comment: Hi brad it would be all the Mth1 Mth2 fields there about fifty of them so there is i need it only to return one row of the sums so that doesnt really help me its that would need to go into sum kinda of tempory table for all the account refs.

Comment: Change it to sum(field) + sum(field2) ......